# Loop through an array using $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson, weather-api

I'm using a for loop to iterate on an array of dates. This array is passed into the JSON request. Problem is that each time it loops it's only pulling the first item in the array.. like it's ignoring `i` or its cached for some reason. I've tried two different approaches and both give me the same results. Any suggestions?

**First approach**

```
for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {

    (function(i) { 

    $.getJSON(url + apiKey + "/" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "," + aryDates[i] + "?callback=?", function(data) {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");

       listItem.className = "js-day-temp";
       $('.js-forecast').append(listItem);
       $('.js-day-temp').html(Math.floor(data.daily.data[0].temperatureMin) + '&#176;');
    });

    })(i);
}
```

**Second approach**

```
for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {

$.ajax({
    url: url + apiKey + "/" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "," + aryDates[i] + "?callback=?",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.className = "js-day-temp";
    $('.js-forecast').append(listItem);
    $('.js-day-temp').html(Math.floor(data.daily.data[0].temperatureMin) + '&#176;');
    }
  });

}
```

**And this is how I pull dates**

```
function GetDates(startDate, daysToAdd) {
var aryDates = [];
var currentDay = [];

for(var i = 0; i <= daysToAdd; i++) {
   var currentDate = new Date();
  currentDate.setUTCDate(startDate.getUTCDate() + i);
  currentDay.push(DayAsString(currentDate.getUTCDay()));
  // aryDates.push(DayAsString(currentDate.getDay()) + ", " +            
currentDate.getDate() + " " + MonthAsString(currentDate.getMonth()) + " " + currentDate.getFullYear());
  aryDates.push(currentDate.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + MonthAsString(currentDate.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + ("0" + (currentDate.getUTCDate()+1)).slice(-2) + "T12:00:00-0400");
 }

return aryDates;
return currentDay;
 }

 function MonthAsString(monthIndex) {
var d=new Date();
var month=new Array();
month[0]="01";
month[1]="02";
month[2]="03";
month[3]="04";
month[4]="05";
month[5]="06";
month[6]="07";
month[7]="08";
month[8]="09";
month[9]="10";
month[10]="11";
month[11]="12";

return month[monthIndex];
}

function DayAsString(dayIndex) {
var weekdays = new Array(7);
weekdays[0] = "Sunday";
weekdays[1] = "Monday";
weekdays[2] = "Tuesday";
weekdays[3] = "Wednesday";
weekdays[4] = "Thursday";
weekdays[5] = "Friday";
weekdays[6] = "Saturday";

return weekdays[dayIndex];
}

var startDate = new Date();
var aryDates = GetDates(startDate, 7);
```

Comment: You're mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. Seek promises.

Comment: no matter which approach you take, it should fire 8 request, each request url varies at the part of date. Have debugged? it should be very easy to see in every loop, what's the value of i and in network section, you should see the 8 requests.

Comment: @AaronShen Yeah it returns 8 requests but it's not iterating through the array. For some reason it runs 8 times but it only pull from the array once then the following requests are duplicates. Instead of going through it one by one. If I console.log(aryDates[i]) inside the JSON request though it logs and iterates through it perfect. Not sure why it won't in the URL request

Comment: @Aaron, Have you checked the exact 8 urls have been fired? Are they the exactly the same?  Or you're just checking the returned results? I mean simply check the exact urls sent, if they're different and expected, then the problem is somewhere else. I don't believe the url is going to be the same if the elements in the array are different.

Comment: @Aaron Show us `aryDates` array?

Comment: @Aaron, I've put your code in a pen:  http://codepen.io/hatelove85911/pen/MyLmGo

there's are some syntax issues in your code I've fixed, the code is a little messy, I simply use your 1st approach after I got an array of date using your last code snippet, and it's firing different url requests as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out! Here's what I changed:

```
$('.js-forecast').append('<li class="js-day-temp ' + 'day-selector' + i + '">' + aryDates[i] + '</li>');
$('.js-day-temp.day-selector' + i).html(Math.floor(data.currently.temperature) + '&#176;');
```